# I know what I'm doing, thanks. But can you still please help me?

Tags: discussion, comments, low-quality-posts

*(Please tell me if this is the wrong place for such a question / comment and feel free to move this question somewhere else. I am also pretty sure similar things may have been discussed before.)*

**The situation**

I love StackExchange because of the fast response and the high quality of answers you get. **But:**

Over the past months either my questions have dropped significantly in quality (that could of course be an explanation), or it's a real trend that more and more people do not try to answer the question itself but start to fuss about why I would ask such a question.

This then leads to long discussions in the comments about why it is wrong to ask such a question and where I possibly went wrong in the beginning.

That is fine as long as it's helping and I appreciate if people try to understand the problem I am working on. **However, I see more and more people embarking on discussions that are a pure matter of taste.**

As an example if I try to define a shortcut in LaTeX that makes it faster for me to write LaTeX documents, and I need help to do so, then I am happy that I get a quick answer. But I do not want to have to justify why I want this shortcut. Or to hear that it is misleading and not useful or whatever.

**Questions**

Is it just me or do others have that impression, too? Could it be a reaction to the increasing popularity of SE, with the potential consequence that indeed the average quality of questions decreases?

How do I react to these comments? Just ignore them? Do I have to justify my question? Should I include a justification already in the question, anticipating such comments? (In fact I have the feeling, the more I try to justify, the more people feel encouraged to dispute the validity of the question.)

Comment: Speaking only to where you choose to ask this question, there's enough of a network between [se] sites that I suspect a vast change in dynamics as you describe will affect many sites, so here is probably reasonably if that's the case, but if you're worried only about a specific site, you'd probably be better-off to post on that site's meta.

Comment: Thanks -- indeed, I posted this topic here because I noticed this behavior coming up at least on two sites (LaTeX and stackoverflow). Probably because I am most active there, I guess it's similar on other sites. So it might be best discussed here.

Comment: If you're doing it wrong, I'm going to say you're doing it wrong.  Not doing so only serves to do a disservice.  For example, you ask me what sort of helmet you should buy.  "Why?  What are your needs?" "Oh, I keep hitting myself in the head with a sledgehammer.  Need to protect myself from not just contusions but also concussions."  "No, you don't need a helmet, you need to stop hitting yourself in the head." "SHUT UP I DO WHAT I WANT DONT PATRONIZE ME IF YOU DONT KNOW THE ANSWER LEAVE ME ALONE!"  You may need to do it, but if it's dumb, suck it up when someone tells you the real solution.

Comment: Have you read my question before downvoting and coming up with your example that totally misses the point?